# Conversion of multiple internal types to system level types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, boost

At my workplace, I am working on a use case where I have to convert multiple internal/product level data types to C++ compatible data types. Earlier we used something called as `switch fence` where code would look like

```
switch(InternalTypeCategory)
{

case InternalTypeA:
           convert_to_int8_t;
           break;

case InternalTypeB:
           convert_to_int16_t
           break;

.....

}
```

But for the sake of performance and other related issues, we are going to convert this `switch fence` block to C++ template based code where we dont have use switch case every now and then.

What have I tried so far?

I have been playing around with `boost::any`, `boost::variant` and `boost::any_cast`, `boost::numeric_cast` but nothing concrete has come up so far. I always end up with repetition of code or use some sort of mechanism (control structures or hash table) to select the particular value to have enough information for type conversion.

The internal/product level data types are variants (in terms of size, signed/unsigned) of integer, floating point, double and character.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If the data-types can handle the I/O operator `<<` and `>>` then maybe use [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) as an intermediary? Write the custom data object to the stream, read into some other type.

Comment: @Joachim please note that he said "for the sake of performance"... I rather doubt that stringstream is better than a switch/case.

Comment: @Daniel True, but then I don't really see a need for rewriting. To the OP, what you have right now is going to be hard to perform better. It all depends on use-cases though, and you really need to benchmark and measure all possible solutions, starting which profiling what you have now to see if that's really the bottle-neck you think it is.

Answer (score 0):

Templates only help you if the type is defined at compile-time. Since you're using a variant, I assume that this is not possible.

However a simple approach is to use a table of conversion methods and then use the internalType as index for these methods.

Create a generic interface for all conversion functions:

```
typedef InternalVariant (*conversionFunc_ptr)(const InternalVariant& data);
```

define an array of all available functions and assign as necessary:

```
static conversionFunc_ptr conversionFunc[MaxInternalTypeCategory];

conversionFunc[InternalTypeA] = convert_to_int8;
conversionFunc[InternalTypeB] = convert_to_int16;
[...]
```

And in the actual function use it like this:

```
return conversionFunc[InternalTypeCategory](*this);
```

Note: You shouldn't use instance members but static members. So you need to supply the variable to the function (otherwise you need to have the conversion array for each value instead only once)